# Knockout Reference Error - Property Is Undefined When It's Present

Tags: javascript, knockout.js

I'm making an AJAX call with JQuery and sending up JSON from an MVC controller.  When the success callback runs, I pass it to an observable on my view model.  So I have a property on the view model named list, and I send up this JSON:

```
{ Items: [ { .. }, { .. }] }
```

The template and container looks like:

```
<div data-bind="template: {name:'Template', data:list}"></div>

<script type="text/html" id="Template">
    <section class="List">
            <ul id="MyList" data-bind="foreach:Items">
```

I try to bind this to a view, and I get an error:

```
Microsoft JScript runtime error: Unable to parse bindings.
Message: ReferenceError: 'Items' is undefined;
Bindings value: foreach:Items
```

Items is correct, it's getting assigned to the view model correctly, and I verified the Items property is really not undefined.  I have the same exact code in another view, and yet it works there and not here.  Any idea why, and what this error is caused by?

**EDIT:** I have a view model that looks like, and is bound to, like so:

```
function viewModel() {
   var self = this;
   self.list = ko.observable(null);
}

$.ajax({
.
.
   context: model, //reference to view model, which is a valid reference
   success: function(d) {
     this.list(d);  //d is JSON laid out above
   }
});
```

Thanks.

Comment: does it exist when the bindings are applied?

Comment: you haven't supplied much code,  but from what you say, if you get Items via ajax,  and the bindings are applied before the Ajax call,  then it won't exist.

Comment: Yeah, Keith probably has that right, try creating a fiddle and we should be able to figure it out for sure.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following should work:

```
<div data-bind="template: {name:'Template', data:list}"></div>

<script type="text/html" id="Template">
    <section class="List">
            <ul id="MyList" data-bind="foreach:Items">
                <span data-bind="text: value"></span>
            </ul>
    </section>
</script>
```

And then use this as your javascript:

```
function viewModel() {
   var self = this;
   self.list = ko.observable();

   self.init = function()
   {
       var data = { Items: [ { value: 1 }, { value: 2 }] }
       self.list(data);
   };

   self.init();
}

ko.applyBindings(new viewModel());
```

Inside the `init` function you execute your ajax call and bind the data.

Comment: Null data was the reason for the problem; when I did: self.list = ko.observable({ Items: [] }); it worked fine.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure what this means, but I think you should get an error because 'd' is not your list above, it's the argument to your function.  Shouldn't you store your view model in a variable and change this:

```
 success: function(d) {
     d.list(d);  //d is JSON laid out above
 }
```

to this:

```
 success: function(d) {
     viewModel.list(d);  // d is JSON laid out above
 }
```

Comment: Yes, that was a typo, I've since changed to this, which is the model (via the context).  Thanks for the catch.